# How do i use a useState variable outside the component in the same file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I was working on a project that fetches data from swiggy api, but now I have added routing to the project. I don't know how can I use a state variable outside of the component but in the same file.

I'm trying to access the api in element : `<BodyLayout api={api} />`.

```
const App = () => {
  const [api, setAPI_KEY] = useState(PUNE_API);

  const handleAPIKeyChange = (newAPIKey) => {
    console.log("API Key changed to:", newAPIKey);

    setAPI_KEY(newAPIKey);
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Header onAPIKeyChange={handleAPIKeyChange} />
      <Outlet/>
      
      <Footer />
    </div>
  ); 
};

const appRoute = createBrowserRouter([
  {
      path : "/",
      element : <App/>,
      errorElement : <RouterError/>,
      children:[
        {
          path : "/home",
          element : <BodyLayout api={api} />,
          
      },
        {
          path : "/",
           element : <BodyLayout api={api} />,
         
      },
        {
          path : "/about",
          element : <About/>,
      },
      {
        path : "/contact",
        element : <Contact/>,
       
      },
      {
        path : "/cart",
        element : <Cart/>,
       
      },
      {
        path : "/offers",
        element : <Offers/>,
       
      },
      ],
  },
]);
 
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<RouterProvider router={appRoute}/>);
```

I have tried multiple ways but none have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`<Outlet>`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) is also a context provider. You can pass values via the `context` property (see type decleration), and then retrieve them with [`useOutletContext()`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-outlet-context#useoutletcontext):

```
const App = () => {
  const [api, setAPI_KEY] = useState(PUNE_API);

  const handleAPIKeyChange = (newAPIKey) => {
    setAPI_KEY(newAPIKey);
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Header onAPIKeyChange={handleAPIKeyChange} />
      
      <Outlet context={api} />
      
      <Footer />
    </div>        
  );
};
```

And remove the prop `api` in your routes:

```
{
  path : "/home",
  element : <BodyLayout />,        
},
```

Call `useOutletContext` in the components that actually use the `api` key.

```
const SampleComponent = () => {
  const api = useOutletContext();

  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can created customized hook to call the API and use that returned result ( API result ) in any react component.